# open terminal run command python

Tags: python

I am trying to open a terminal and run a command in it. I am using

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"exec bash; MY_COMMAND; exec bash\" '")
```

This opens up a new terminal, but the command is not executed.

Comment: Why do you surround your command with `exec bash`?

Comment: Do you need to run this in a terminal? What about subprocess python module?

Comment: @zondo it keeps the terminal open after execution

Comment: @RaydelMiranda it needs to run in a terminal

Comment: Well, you don't need that beforehand. What I do is: `MY_COMMAND; echo Hit ^C to close this terminal; while true; do sleep 2; done`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `exec` command replaces the currently running process with a new one, so if you have an exec in a list of commands to run, as soon as exec is run, nothing else will run.  So you're replacing `'bash -c \"exec bash; MY_COMMAND; exec bash\" '` with `bash`, and then nothing after the `exec bash` is running.  Try this instead:

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"MY_COMMAND\" '")
```

or if you need a terminal to stay open, try this:

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"MY_COMMAND; sleep 1000000\" '")
```

of if you want the terminal to stay open and be in a bash shell, try this:

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"MY_COMMAND; bash\" '")
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to open a tab and run "MY_COMMAND" instead of new terminal every time?

Comment: how to close that terminal?

Comment: @sutirtha that would depend on the terminal and whether the terminal supports opening a new tab from within a session. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/211050/96913) for a way that may work.

Answer (score 6):

## Here we go...

```
command="python3 --version"
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \""+command+";bash\"'")
```

That should do it...

```
Output:Python 3.6.4
```

And the output came into a new terminal....

Answer (score 1):

**How to open and close that terminal after running the command**

You can run this command in python file

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"sudo -S <<< Notadmin apt-get update && exit; exec bash\"'")
```

In this command, we have multiple parameters

1. It will open a terminal first.
2. it will run simple and sudo commands as well.
3. after installing it will close automatically.

I m using Ubuntu 20.04 and using this command in my API. and it works fine.

```
**sudo -S <<< Notadmin apt-get update**
```

- **-S** this parameter to read password '**Notadmin**' is my system password

This will work without sudo

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"pip install python && exit; exec bash\"'")
```